# jQuery - Moving a Link which has no class/id

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm coding an Enjin website. And theres a dropdown which has all the admin panel options on it. This is the image of what it looks like, after I've added a bootstrap navigation bar.[image]

As you can see, Admin has places itself over the last dropdown from the navigation bar. The admin dropdown has code which looks like this:

```
<div class="left">
        <a href="/" style="display: none;">CorruptionCraft</a><span class="divider">|</span><a href="/admin"></a><a href="/admin" onmouseover="Enjin_Core.dropdownMenu([['Users','/admin/users',0],['Games','/admin/games',0],['Pages','/admin/layout',0],['Modules','/admin/modules',0],['Voice','/admin/voice',0],['Themes','/admin/themelayout',0],['Files','/admin/files',0],['Settings','/admin/settings',0],['','divider'],['&lt;a href=\'javascript:void(0);\' class=\'menu-link\' onclick=\'Enjin_Core.toggleEditMode(this);\'&gt;Quick edit&lt;/a&gt;', 'html'],['&lt;a class=\'menu-link\' href=\'/admin/layout/index/page/3661170\'&gt;Edit page layout&lt;/a&gt;', 'html'],['','divider'],['Help Wiki','http://wiki.enjin.com',1],['Live Help Chat','http://www.enjin.com/forums#livehelp',1],['Support Forums','http://www.enjin.com/forums',1],['Email Support','http://www.enjin.com/support/form',1]], $(this), 'enjinbar-menu');"><span style="">Admin</span></a><span class="arrow" style="border-top-color: gray;"></span>       </div>
```

As you can see, it has no relative ID or class. When moving it previously, I used jQuery to add in a padding for the link:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $.get('/login/do/joinsite', function(data) {});
 $("a[href^='/admin']:contains('Admin')").html("<span style='padding-left:80px'>Admin</span>");
```

However, although it moves the link along to the desired place, all of the padding is still linked. So, when hovering over where the Admin text would be without the padding, it still opens the dropdown. I'm looking to move the text along completely, without having this annoying bug.
As you can see in this image:
[image: Image 2]
Excuse my paint usage - but you can hopefully see the issue, and provide me with a fix. As Enjin is a website builder, I cannot just go edit the Admin code directly, and need some extra code to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`padding` extends the clickable area. You should use `margin` instead, but not on the `<span/>` you create inside the `<a/>`. Apply it directly to the `<a/>`:

```
$("a[href^='/admin']:contains('Admin')").css("margin-left", "80px");
```